# Dispose Form opened in MainForm tab

Tags: vb.net, controls, dispose, tabs

I have a MainForm which has tab Control and several independent form. I open each Individual From in the tab of the main form. A "Close Tab" button on the MainFrom closes the current tab, its implementation is below.

This closes the current tab but what I also need is to dispose the From whose tab is closed but I am not sure how to get the instance of the form.'

Any help is appreciated Thanks in Advance.

```
'Close the current tab
  Private Sub CloseCurrentTab()
    'Close the current tab 

      Dim tabPageSave As TabPage
      tabPageSave = tcDisplayDetails.SelectedTab
      tcDisplayDetails.TabPages.Remove(tabPageSave)
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'll need to dispose *all* of the controls in the tab page.  The form isn't special, it is just a child control when you set its TopLevel property to false.  Make it look like this:

```
  Dim tabPageSave As TabPage
  tabPageSave = tcDisplayDetails.SelectedTab
  While tabPageSave.Controls.Count > 0
      tabPageSave.Controls(0).Dispose()
  End While
  tcDisplayDetails.TabPages.Remove(tabPageSave)
```

The form's Dispose() method will automatically dispose any child controls it has, no additional help is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest keeping a reference to the forms in the main form. So I'd have a frmPageSave and when I open the form for the PageSave tab I store the reference in that variable and then in your CloseCurrentTab method I'd add something like:

```
IF frmPageSave IsNot Nothing Then
    frmPageSave.Close()
    frmPageSave = Nothing
End If
```